# C++20 Unable to Satisfy Constraint for ranges::remove_if()

Tags: compiler-errors, c++17, std-ranges, remove-if

I have the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
private:
    T item_;
public:
    T Item() const {return item_;}
    Node(T item) : item_(item) {}
    Node<T>& operator=(T item) { item_ = item; return *this;}
    Node<T>& operator=(Node<T> &rhs) { item_ = rhs.Item(); return *this;}
};
```

And I try to erase `nodes` object from `vector` which have values `< 0`.

```
vector<Node<int>> nodes(10);
ranges::generate(nodes, [n = -5]() mutable {return n++; });
nodes.erase(ranges::remove_if(nodes, [](const Node<int>& n) { return n.Item() < 0; }).begin(), nodes.end());
```

However, I keep getting compilation error:

```
1>C:\Projects\C++\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.cpp(8698,22): error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\Projects\C++\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.cpp(8698,86): error C7602: 'std::ranges::_Remove_if_fn::operator ()': the associated constraints are not satisfied
```

It happens even if I try to use the `remove_if` overload with `&Node<int>::Item` projection.

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: you forgot `return *this;`

Comment: It's there in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after adding the following `=` operator overload:

```
Node<T>& operator=(Node<T> rhs) { item_ = rhs.Item(); return *this; }
```

I wonder why the original `=` operator overload with `rhs` reference doesn't work?

Comment: The assignment operator should generally take a `const&`, not a modifiable one